# How to download password protected files from Edge or Chrome

Tags: coldfusion

How can I download password protected files when downloading the files from Edge or Chrome. Currently, I have code that works for files that are not password protected.

The following is the code I am using:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(URL, 'method') and URL.method eq 'download'>
    <cfset file_name = URL.name />
    <cfset path = URL.path />   
    
    <!--- The following if statements determine file type. ---> 
    <cfif findNoCase('.doc', file_name) or findNoCase('.odt', file_name) or findNoCase('.rtf', file_name) >
        <cfset file_type = 'application/msword' >
    <cfelseif findNoCase('.pdf', file_name) >
        <cfset file_type = 'application/pdf' >
    <cfelseif findNoCase('.xls', file_name) or findNoCase('.xlt', file_name) or findNoCase('.csv', file_name)>
        <cfset file_type = 'application/vnd.ms-excel' >
    <cfelseif findNoCase('.tif', file_name) >
        <cfset file_type = 'image' >
    <cfelseif findNoCase('.jpg', file_name) >
        <cfset file_type = 'image/jpeg' >
    <cfelseif findNoCase('.url', file_name) or findNoCase('.lnk', file_name) >
        <cfset file_type = 'text/uri-list' >    
    </cfif>

    <!--- The following if checks which header to use --->
    <cfif findNoCase('.msg', file_name) or findNoCase('.mdb', file_name) or findNoCase('.wmv', file_name) or findNoCase('.db', file_name)>
        <!--- The following statements creates a downloadable link of the file. This is done by using cfheader and cfcontent --->   
        <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#file_name#">
    <cfelse>
        <!--- The following statements creates a downloadable link of the file. This is done by using cfheader and cfcontent --->   
        <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=#file_name#">
    </cfif>
    
    <!---Check if file type is available. If available, show type. --->
    <cfif isDefined("file_type") >
        <cfcontent type="#file_type#" file="#path#\#file_name#">
    <!--- If file type is not found, display file anyways. --->
    <cfelse>
        <cfcontent file="#path#\#file_name#">
    </cfif>
    <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

Comment: I don't follow. CF won't care if the file is password protected. That's internal to the file. All your code is doing is setting a header and sending the file. How is this code not working for a password-protected file? What precise question/problem are you trying to answer there?

Comment: @AdamCameron So the issue I am encountering is when I select the password protected file, I get the following error: "portal.internal.local sent an invalid response." followed by: "ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION" https://www.ryadel.com/en/err_response_headers_multiple_content_disposition-error-google-chrome-fix/

Comment: Like mentioned in the link you posted, try this `<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value='attachment; filename="#file_name#"'>` wrapping filename in quotes.